# Connection between Residue Theorem in complex analysis and algebraic geometry

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

I am currently studying algebraic curves using the Fulton. In chapter 8 we have a proposition called "Residue Theorem"

RESIDUE THEOREM. Let $C,E$ be as above ($C$ is a projective plane curve, $E = \sum_{Q\in X} (m_{(f(Q)} - 1)\, Q$, $X$ is a non singular model of $C$). Suppose $D$ and $D'$ are effective divisors on $X$, with $D'\equiv D$. Suppose $G$ is an adjoint of degree $m$ such that $\operatorname{div}(G) = D + E + A$ for some effective divisor $A$. Then there is an adjoint $G'$ of degree $m$ such that $\operatorname{div}(G') = D' + E + A$.

I was wondering if this has anything to do with the Residue Theorem in complex analysis. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Not exactly my field of expertise, however [Enzo Martinelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzo_Martinelli) remarks in his lecture notes *Introduzione elementare...* remarks that wide extension to his Integral formula for functions of several complex variables and the associated multidimensional residue theorem(s) are to be found in Griffiths & Harris "*Principles of Algebraic Geometry*": I hope this could be of some help.

Comment: The residue theorem shows that $\deg(div(f)) =\int_{\partial X} \frac{df}{2i \pi f}= 0$ for any meromorphic function. $D \equiv D'$ means there is a meromorphic function with $div(f) = D'-D$ so $G' = f G$ and $\deg(div(G)) - \deg(div(G')) = \deg(div(f)) = 0$

Comment: Can you explain why $deg(div(f)) = \int_{\partial X} \frac{df}{2\pi i f}$ and also why $deg(div(G)) - deg(div(G')) = 0$?

Comment: It depends on your setting and what you don't understand. I'm talking of a complex smooth projective curve seen as a compact Riemann surface. Then $\deg(div(f)) =\int_{\partial X} \frac{df}{2i \pi f}$ is called the "argument principle". The corresponding things for curves over any field are much more abstract.